# There is no "link to Firebase" option in Admob

Tags: firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to link my admob account apps to my firebase analytics. I do these steps https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165

But there is no "Link to Firebase" option in my app's settings.

[image: Picture]

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I am facing this same issue. No "Link to Firebase." option there. Did you get any solution for it? Thanks.

Comment: No, still facing the problem.